# Rerendering in GXT

Tags: java, model-view-controller, gwt, gxt, rerender

I am using the GXT MVC framework in my application. I have a toolbar and when I click on an item in the toolbar, the application redirects to a given page. (which is a ContentPanel I add to the View). The problem here is, that somehow the ContentPanel will not be removed after I navigate to another page (= View with Contentpanel). When navigating again to the first page, the onRender method of the contentPanel will NOT be called again and I get my old page.

So my question is, how can I force a ContentPanel to rerender? I tried with removing and adding to the parent and doing a layout().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should invoke method fireEvent(Events.Render) of ContentPanel object?